# When I refresh my Reagent page, Firebase data isn't available so I get an exception

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, om, reagent

I've a Reagent that works on all pages while clicking back & forward buttons. However, it throws an exception when a page is REFRESHED.

My app fetches data from Firebase and `sets` an atom. Then as the UI is rendered. The view grabs data from the atom and renders a UI.

But when I refresh, it seems like the page is rendered before my Atom is populated by Firebase and that causes an exception because the data isn't available yet.

Note: when I refresh the page just `(println clicked-job uid)`, not rendering markup, the `println` runs twice, the first time returning `nil` and the second returning the data.

```
/* Atom */
(def current-view (atom {"jobs-list" {}}))

/* Helper Functions */
(defn set-list! [value]
  (swap! app-state assoc-in ["jobs-list"] value))

(defn clicked-job [uid]
  (get-in @app-state ["jobs-list" uid]))

/* View */
(defn job-view [uid]
  (let [job clicked-job uid)]  
    [:div
      [:div (job "name")]  /***THROWS EXCEPTION HERE***/
      [:a.routes {:href "#/"} "home page"])

/* Fetch data from Firebase and put it in Atom */
(let [fb (js/Firebase. "https://firebaseio.com/listings")]
   (.on fb "value" #(set-list! (js->clj (.val %)))))

/* Set app-view to current-view */
(defn app-view []
    [:div (@data/current-view)])

/* Render app-view */
(reagent/render-component [app-view] (.getElementById js/document "app"))
```

Any help to make the page refresh properly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I needed a "Gateway" to make sure my render code doesn't run if my state wasn't ready.

Easy way to do this is an if statement. If my atom has not yet been set by Firebase, do nothing. If it is set, render view. And since Reagent renders views automatically as the data is changed, you don't have to worry about any further wiring up.

Here's a pseudo code example:

```
 (if (empty? (data/get-list!))
   (println "True. Atom is empty. Do not start rendering.")
   (render-view)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

the other thing you could do is use defonce instead of def for your atom. this will prevent your atom form being redefined when you reload the page. Have a look at [the figwheel page](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel), at the end is a useful section on writing reloadable code.